# Hosting Multiple Asp.net Core projects under one domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, cpanel, shared-hosting

My solution has different shared projects(Class Library) and 3 Asp.net Core Web Applications. I have published and hosted one of the project and its working fine with  https://example.com/home/Index.
How can i host other 2 projects , in  such a way that i can access them by https://example.com/WebApp2/home/Index and https://example.com/WebApp2/home/Index. I tried configuring them as virtual directories but getting HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

Comment: They need to be virtual apps, not virtual directories.

Comment: Makes sure that that the projects have different port numbers as well.

Comment: I would recommend you to create it as subdomain on your control panel, it is something like abc.yourdomain.com, you can test this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different applications under your web site in IIS and then deploy different ASP.NET core projects to the different applications.

More information about how to create application you can refer to this link:
[application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/)